# How to reload a Java Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to refresh my GUI each time a function is triggered.
This is how I defined the skeleton of the GUI:

```
public class GUI {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void runGui() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI window = new GUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                window.frame.setSize(800, 600);
                window.frame.setTitle("My Title");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
 public GUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
//CODE
}
```

So, the GUI.runGui() function is called in a function like:

```
public void myFunction()
{
 //CODE
 GUI.runGui();
}
```

The problem is the following: every time this function is called, it generates a new instance of the GUI, so I end up having multiple instances. This is not what I want, since I just need to refresh the content of the GUI that must be only one.
I believe the problem is architectural.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You should edit the question to describe *exactly* what "refreshing" should mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? Is there some data that needs to be displayed? Do you have an animation? Or something else? Each of these will have a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what runGui is doing: it's creating and initializing a GUI every time you call it. Pull that one time initialization code out of runGui and into another place that you run once (like the initialize method). And in runGui access a component that you want to refresh (perhaps the content pane) as:

```
// This needs to become an instance method (non static) in this example in
// order to access the frame
public void runGui() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Refresh your component here. Here I'm redrawing the
            // content pane

            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it's easier to manage the GUI using it as a variable. Unluckly it gives me NullPointer Exception when I call frame.getContentPane().repaint();
I also created a function "refresh" with this line of code (I also tried some repaint and revalidate), but still NullPointerException. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Wall *You* are not really missing something, but everybody who's trying to help you is. Namely, we're missing an *exact* description of what "refresh" should mean. (A side note: The code shown in this answer, for itself, does not make sense. `repaint()` is one of the few methods that can be called from any thread, and as long as it's not clear that "refresh" should mean, repainting will likely not solve the issue...)

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.repaint();
```

This article contains some repaint examples:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javax.swing.JFrame&method=repaint

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get the content pane from the `frame` and then use `.repaint()`.  You can do the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

Comment: Hi Kamolesh and welcome to SO. Usually the posts with some explanation receiving more upvotes. Would you like to update your answer to provide some explanation and improve formatting?